# How do i move a file from one directory to another on the same server on PHP

Tags: php, sql, file

I'm trying to copy one file from a directory to another upon execution of an sql query but it doesn't work.

```
if($result){
    $path = "forms/uploads/";
    $file = $path.$request_name."docx";
    if(file_exists($file)){
        move_uploaded_file($file, "forms/requests/") ;
   }
    echo 400;
```

The $path is the directory where the file currently exists.

Comment: is it a file that you have just uploaded? If yes it is the `tmp` copy of the file that you move

Comment: Has the file actually been uploaded? If not, you want [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.rename.php)

Comment: No the file wasn't just uploaded. It was uploaded before and now i want to move it to another folder after my sql statement executes

Comment: @Phil Yes the file has been uploaded. It is in the uploads folder and i want to move it to the requests folder after the sql

Comment: @Phil Yes the file has been uploaded. It is in the uploads folder and i want to move it to the requests folder after the sql

Comment: I'd you're not moving a just uploaded file from its temporary location, then you cannot use `move_uploaded_file()`. As I said before, use `rename()`

Comment: Stop marking down this question please. Whoever you are

Answer (score 1):

You can try use copy function and unlink old file

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

```
    if($result){
        $path = "forms/uploads/";
        $file = $path.$request_name."docx";
        $newfile = $path.$request_name."docx";
        if(file_exists($file)){
           if (!copy($file, "forms/requests/".$newfile)) {
                 echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
            }
          unlink($file);
    } 
    echo 400;
```